# Increase icons size in GNOME Shell 3.4 Dash

Tags: icons, customization, gnome-shell

How do I increase the size of icons in the GNOME Shell Dash?

I have tried http://abhizweblog.blogspot.in/2011/06/gnome3-change-icon-size.html and tried changing the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/dash.js` file as well, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Editing the gnome-shell.css file is the right way. Have you tried to restart Gnome Shell (press [Alt] + [F2] and type "r"), to log off or to reboot?

Comment: yes, tried it but of no use (restarted gnome shell and relogin but not reboot)

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the opposite problem of decreasing icons size in gnome shell on an ubuntu GNOME 14.04 fresh install through the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/dash.js` file.

In addition to the modifications in the `gnome-shell.cs` file mentioned on your link and a few other ones, I changed the value on line 14 in the `dash.js` file.

See https://askubuntu.com/a/450749/271033.