# Size of icons on Ubuntu 12.04 with GNOME 3

Tags: 12.04, gnome, icons

I have never had any difficulties changing size of icons. Now the main trouble is that change of `-shell-grid-item-size` does not take effect. I was sure that `-shell-grid-item-size` defined the size of container (an icon and its paddings). But whatever value I install noting changes.

```
.icon-grid {
    spacing: 25px;
    -shell-grid-item-size: 50px;
}

.all-app .overview-icon {  
    -shell-grid-item-size: 100px;
}
```

I tried the accepted solution from [How to reduce the size of all gnome-shell icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66801/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-all-gnome-shell-icons) and didn't succeed.

**The solution**

I might have forgotten to restart GNOME. `Alt + F2`, type `r`, and press `Enter`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone errs here as I did in search of a clue to tune down (or up, as it also happens) the size of the icons in the applications grid, here is a hint:

https://askubuntu.com/a/450749/271033

As mentioned by Maksim, the changes in the `gnome-shell.css` file affect the size and padding of the *container*, but the size of the *icons* must be changed separately in the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/iconGrid.js` file. Or at least this is what worked for me.