# Get apps on bar below in the gnome shell

Tags: themes, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-shell

I wish to customize my ubuntu gnome shell to something like these pictures in the flax remix theme page.

[image: Flat-remix screenshot]

I have already installed flat remix but there is no app list at bottom. I really loved the look of those apps as well as the top bar being at the bottom right and want that. What extension do I use for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [MMOD Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/898/mmod-panel/) extension. It changes top-bar into a customisable panel. You might also need [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) to show favourites and running apps in the panel (even though MMOD Panel has an option to do that, Dash to panel has more customisation options).

Comment: It worked perfectly. One small thing though, the icons on the bar are too big. I tried using this [Reduce icon size in gnome shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66801/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-all-gnome-shell-icons). But it only reduced icon size in the overview. Could you help me with this?

Comment: @prateek-dhanuka Use **Dash to Panel** instead of MMOD Panel. It has more customisation options.

Comment: The picture definitely seems to show show **Dash to Panel**. It indeed features a lot of tweaks.